# Show that any function is Hölder -continuous is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I realize that similar questions have been asked on the site, but none of them have really helped me to understand. I'm not even sure how to approach this question. I am guessing that I have to prove that the limit of such a function at any point is equal to the function at that point, but even with that I am not sure how to start this problem. Any help to at least get started would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show some work. You can use the Hölder bound to show that if $x,y$ are close then $f(x),f(y)$ will be close. Write down the Hölder expression involving $x,y,f(x),f(y)$.

Comment: By definition $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq K|x - y|^{\alpha}$ where $K,\alpha$ are non-negatives. Given $\epsilon > 0$, which $\delta$ you need to take for get $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $| x- y|<\delta$? You will need to analyze $K|x - y|^{\alpha}$

Comment: Thats what I understood from the other thread and found δ must equal (ϵ/K)^α. I just don't understand why that proves continuity.